# Can't Write Into Multiple Columns CSV

Tags: python, csv

I know there are similar questions, but none worked for me. I'm trying to insert a list of lists into a csv file `...` I need each list in the list to be inserted in a row and each item in that list in different columns.

here is the code :

```
all_list = [job_titles_list, company_list, locations_list, skills_list]
ziped = zip_longest(*all_list)

with open('jobs.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Job Title;Company Name;Location;Skills;salary"])
    writer.writerows(ziped)
    file.close()
```

it show like this :

```
| Job Titles                        | company name| Salary|

|senior programmer, Google, 100000  |

|python programmer, Netflix, 200000 |
```

All the data in one column.

I hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the header row you write is just a string

```
writer.writerow(["Job Title;Company Name;Location;Skills;salary"])
```

By default, [the separator is a `,`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer). If you want to use a `;` you should be able to do:

```
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=";")
writer.writerow(["Job Title", "Company", "Name","Location"])
```

I was able to get an output that looks like what you need with the following:

```
import csv
import itertools

job_titles_list = ['senior eng', 'staff eng', 'dev ops']
company_list = ['Google', 'Amazon', 'Netflix']
location_list = ['SF', 'Paris', 'London']

all_list = [job_titles_list, company_list, location_list]
ziped = itertools.zip_longest(*all_list)

with open('jobs.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(["Job Title", "Company", "Location"])
    writer.writerows(ziped)
    file.close()
```

jobs.csv:

```
Job Title;Company;Location
senior eng;Google;SF
staff eng;Amazon;Paris
dev ops;Netflix;London
```

Comment: It worked thank you, so my mistake was only in ` writer.writerow()` ?

Comment: Yes, that's it ! Glad it could help you. If this fixed this issue, could you mark the answer as accepted so the question is resolved @AbdullahKassar ?

Answer (score 1):

CSV is comma separated, so change ";" to be ",". Also, need to process the data, add the string notation `'` to each word

Would you try if this works? (**edited**)

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest
import re

job_titles_list = ['Senior Python Developer, Senior Full Stack Instructor (PHP-Python) ,Python Developer']
job_titles_list = [e.strip() for e in job_titles_list[0].split(',')]

company_list = ['Trufla -, Confidential -, Fekra Technology Solutions']
company_list = [e.strip() for e in re.split(',[^"]', company_list[0])]

locations_list = ['"Heliopolis, Cairo, Egypt", "Cairo, Egypt " , "Dokki, Giza, Egypt " ']
locations_list = [e.strip() for e in re.findall('"(.*?)"', locations_list[0])]

skills_list = ['4+ Yrs of Exp · IT/Software Development · Engineering, 6-7 Yrs of Exp · IT/Software , 4+ Yrs of Exp · IT/Soft etc']
# skills_list = [x.replace('•', '|') for x in skills_list]    #might need to replace the non-Unicode character if any
skills_list = [e.strip() for e in re.split(',[^"]', skills_list[0])]

salary_list = [1000, 2000, 3000]
all_list = [job_titles_list, company_list, locations_list, skills_list, salary_list]
ziped = zip_longest(*all_list)

with open('jobs.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Job Title','Company Name','Location','Skills','salary'])
    writer.writerows(ziped)
    file.close()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but it didn't work, do you have an idea why? (see the image in my answer)

Comment: It depends on your data format. Should be in quotation marks like `['Senior Python Dev', 'Trufla', 'etc']`. You need to process the data first, follow the format in my answer like `locations_list = ['SF', 'Paris', 'London']`

Comment: hey I've edited my answer yesterday, to be similar to your excel picture, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

(replying to @danPho )

It wrote it all in one column
[image: This what it shows me]