# How do I extract location names from a string with mixed commas and quotation marks? (using Regex or any other methods)

Tags: python, string, list, extract

I have a string of locations

```
locations = 'Los Angeles California ,"Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt",Berlin Germany, Paris France," Cairo, Egypt " , "Dokki, Giza, Egypt " , Singapore'
```

Note that the location names are separated by commas. But for each name with commas in between, it is enclosed in double quotation marks. Also there are prefix/suffix white spaces to be stripped.

After extracting the names into a list, the result should be:

```
['Los Angeles California', 'Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt', 'Berlin Germany', 'Paris France', 'Cairo, Egypt', 'Dokki, Giza, Egypt', 'Singapore']
```

I have tried this and it is able to get the results. But I'm laughing at my work because it looks so cumbersome

```
import re

locations = 'Los Angeles California ,"Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt",Berlin Germany, Paris France," Cairo, Egypt " , "Dokki, Giza, Egypt " , Singapore'
lis1 = [e.strip() for e in re.findall('"(.*?)"', locations)]
temp = []
for strg in lis1:
    temp.extend([x.strip() for x in strg.split(',')])
lis2 = [e.strip() for e in locations.split(',')]
for strg in lis2:
    if strg.strip('"').strip() not in temp:
        lis1.append(strg)
print(lis1)
```

So I'm reaching out to the community... Is there a better solution using Regex or any other methods?

Comment: To avoid an X-Y problem, where are you pulling the data from, and with what code?

Comment: I was learning Regex from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73319718/cant-write-into-multiple-columns-csv). I was challenging myself to solve it if the data were to be mixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (this doesn't use regex)

```py
locations = 'Los Angeles California ,"Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt",Berlin Germany, Paris France," Cairo, Egypt " , "Dokki, Giza, Egypt " , Singapore'

in_string = False
out = ['']

for char in locations:
    if char == '"':
        in_string = not in_string
        continue
    if char == ',':
        if not in_string:
            out.append('')
            continue
    out[-1] += char

print([x.strip() for x in out])
```

Output:

```py
['Los Angeles California',
 'Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt',
 'Berlin Germany',
 'Paris France',
 'Cairo, Egypt',
 'Dokki, Giza, Egypt',
 'Singapore']
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried in javascript to get an answer in a single line. Here is another possible solution:

**Javascript:**

```
locations = 'Los Angeles California ,"Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt",Berlin Germany, Paris France," Cairo, Egypt " , "Dokki, Giza, Egypt " , Singapore, "Kolkata, India", Nepal, Bhutan';

locations.replace(/\"[\w\s, ]+\"/gi, x => x.replace(/,/g, '\\').replace(/\"/g, '').trim()).split(',').map(x => x.replace(/\\/g, ',').trim())
```

Output:

```
[
  "Los Angeles California", 
   "Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt", 
   "Berlin Germany", 
   "Paris France", 
   "Cairo, Egypt", 
   "Dokki, Giza, Egypt", 
   "Singapore", 
   "Kolkata, India", 
   "Nepal", 
   "Bhutan"
]
```

Explanation:

- find the combination of strings between `\" (double inverted commas)`.

  - Then replace all `commas (,)` with `Backslash (\)` : I am using backslash because it's not used in Location generally.
  - remove `\" (double inverted commas)`
- Now split the sting with `comma (,)` and replace `Backslash (\)` with `comma (,)`

**In Python:**

```
import re

locations = 'Los Angeles California ,"Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt",Berlin Germany, Paris France," Cairo, Egypt " , "Dokki, Giza, Egypt " , Singapore, "Kolkata, India", Nepal, Bhutan'

l = [e for e in re.sub("\"[\w\s, ]+\"", 'xxxxx', locations).split(',') if 'xxxxx' not in e] + re.findall('"(.*?)"', locations)
print([e.strip() for e in l])
```

Output:

```
['Los Angeles California',
 'Berlin Germany',
 'Paris France',
 'Singapore',
 'Nepal',
 'Bhutan',
 'Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt',
 'Cairo, Egypt',
 'Dokki, Giza, Egypt',
 'Kolkata, India']
```

Comment: would you explain what does `\"?` do in Regex?

Comment: I am breaking the string if there are any \" matching at start or end

Comment: oh i think "Berlin Germany, Paris France" is not broken up

Comment: Ya, this is an issue. I will look into it. It's a tricky thing to resolve in a single line using regex.

Comment: then maybe in 2 lines like that in @Gold79's answer?

Comment: I have posted another solution to execute in a single line. But in Javascript, I have done and regex is as follows:

`locations.replace(/\"[\w\s, ]+\"/gi, x => x.replace(/,/g, '\\').replace(/\"/g, '').trim()).split(',').map(x => x.replace(/\\/g, ',').trim())`. 

I don't know how to write it in Python. Basically the inner lambda function. Is that possible to write this regex in Python?

Comment: I've edited your post to include a possible way to do it in python, pls have a look and up my question if it's acceptable to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to solve it

```
import re 

locations = 'Los Angeles California ,"Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt",Berlin Germany, Paris France," Cairo, Egypt " , "Dokki, Giza, Egypt " , Singapore'
lis1 = [e.strip() for e in re.findall('"(.*?)"', locations)]
templis = ''.join(re.split('".*?"', locations))
lis2 = [e.strip() for e in templis.split(',') if len(e.strip()) > 0]

print(lis1 + lis2)

['Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt',
 'Cairo, Egypt',
 'Dokki, Giza, Egypt',
 'Los Angeles California',
 'Berlin Germany',
 'Paris France',
 'Singapore']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
locations = 'Los Angeles California ,"Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt",Berlin Germany, Paris France," Cairo, Egypt " , "Dokki, Giza, Egypt " , Singapore'
locations = locations.strip(',')
locations=locations.split('"')

result=[]
for i in locations:
    i = i.strip()
    i = i.rstrip(',')
    i = i.lstrip(',')
    if i=="":
        continue
    else:
        result.append(i)

print([e.strip() for e in result])
```

**Output**

```
['Los Angeles California',
 'Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt',
 'Berlin Germany, Paris France',
 'Cairo, Egypt',
 'Dokki, Giza, Egypt',
 'Singapore']
```

Comment: No Problem wait a minute.

Comment: Updated. Kindly Check it.

Comment: hi @Mehmaam, there should be 7 locations, but you have 6 (because `Berlin Germany` and `Paris France` are counted together)

Answer (score 0):

```
[l.strip() for l in locations.split(",")]
```

Comment: please update your locations variable

Comment: sorry the output should be a list with `'Los Angeles California'`,   `'Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt'`,   `'Berlin Germany'`,   `'Paris France'`,   `'Cairo, Egypt'`,   `'Dokki, Giza, Egypt'`,   `'Singapore'`

Comment: hi @SachinSalve, this answer does *not* output the correct results

Answer (score 0):

Today I had retried and finally, I did that and got an answer in a single line.

In Javascript:

```
locations = `Los Angeles California ,"Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt",Berlin Germany, Paris France," Cairo, Egypt " , "Dokki, Giza, Egypt " , Singapore, "Kolkata, India", Nepal, Bhutan`;

locations.replace(/\"[\w\s, ]+\"/gi, x => x.replace(/,/g, '\\').replace(/\"/g, '').trim()).split(',').map(x => x.replace(/\\/g, ',').trim())
```

Output:

```
[
  "Los Angeles California", 
   "Heliopolis, Central, Cairo, Egypt", 
   "Berlin Germany", 
   "Paris France", 
   "Cairo, Egypt", 
   "Dokki, Giza, Egypt", 
   "Singapore", 
   "Kolkata, India", 
   "Nepal", 
   "Bhutan"
]
```

Explanation:

- find the combination of strings between `\" (double inverted commas)`.

  - Then replace all `commas (,)` with `Backslash (\)` : I am using backslash because it's not used in Location generally.
  - remove `\" (double inverted commas)`
- Now split the sting with `comma (,)` and replace `Backslash (\)` with `comma (,)`

I am able to write that in python.

```
str.replace(find_st, x => x.replace(find_st1, rep_st))
```

Because how I don't know how I express the above expression in this in Python. Basically the inner function.

Can anyone help to write the above regular expression in Python in a single line?